# Issue in Virtual Keyboard in blackberry device when coded with jquery and phone gap

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry

I am new to jquery and phone gap
I have coded a page which has text field and a button 
On click of a button A virtual keyboard shows up for typing and then when hidden the page does not scroll back to normal state it shows a blank state in the area where virtual keyboard was initailly
I am using jquery and phonegap for coding it works fine in andriod and iphone devices but this issue is seen only on blackberry device .
What's the issue?

:

[image: Normal State]

[image: Virtual Keyboard Active State]

[image: Virtual Keyboard hidden and Disturbed State]